# I'm not able to find any information on this error I'm seeing "StreamResetError('Stream forcefully closed',)" while trying Apple Push Notifications

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

I'm running a Python application server using Flask on an AWS EC2 micro instance. I'm trying to send push notifications using this [apns2](https://github.com/Pr0Ger/PyAPNs2) package.

I don't understand if the "StreamResetError('Stream forcefully closed',)" error is being caused by apple servers, or if it is being caused by my AWS instance. I'm unable to replicate this at will. It happens fairly randomly.

I also couldn't find anything relating APNS to this error online. I'm hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: I ended up catching this exception (`from hyper.http20.exceptions import StreamResetError`) and retrying sending the notification. So far so good. It's seems the HTTP2 connection is sometime closed and a retry is in order.

Comment: **My code**
`
 try:
        stream_id = apns.send_notification_async(device_token, apns_payload, target_app)
        apns_response = apns.get_notification_result(stream_id)
    except StreamResetError:
        logging.error("StreamResetError Exception occurred.")
`

Comment: **How do you know that when this StreamResetError occurred?**
meaning how to know is our notification sent or not because what I have seen is - this error only comes when we request for the notification response.